# How to add buttons from a groupbox to an array

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a groupbox with a bunch of buttons to represent a virtual keyboard, how can I add all these buttons to an array?

Can I use the GetChildren from groupbox?

Comment: I would not put buttons in an array. You should use another structure.

Comment: `[Container].Controls` is already a collection you can you parse/enumerate/filter. If you are going to "pass" those controls to another enumerable structure, there ought to be a meaningful advantage. Also, you should probably already have these controls in a *meaningful* structure (a `List<class>` maybe), and add them to a Container collection for presentation after. Hence, you can manage your collection of controls no matter where they are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Get All chlids (Controls on groupbox) that are of type `Button` this will return an IEnumerable, and you can then Convert it to Array using `.ToArray()` method of IEnumerable:

```
Button[] btns = groupBox.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
```

Comment: ohh I had a small error in my code, I edited it, please try it again

Comment: Yes, that is what I had tried, maybe something else in my code is wrong

Comment: please note that `groupBox` should be replaced with your own groupbox name. and there was an error in my code, copy the new one.